# Angular share data between service and two components

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to get `Post[]` from http and then I display it on `post-list` component. I can delete some items on `post-list` template, and edit some items by navigating to another route where I use `post-edit` component.
How do I share same `Post[]` array between them so the changes will be instantly displayed in the app? I assume I need to store `Post[]` in the service? what is the correct way to edit/update it from component? 
here I'm trying to save `Post[]` array inside service by `tap()` operator inside the service

```
  getAllPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  }

  getAllUsersPosts(userId: number): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.getAllPosts().pipe(
      map((posts: Post[]) => posts.filter((p: Post) => p.userId === userId)),
      tap(posts => {
        //storing to service
        this.userPosts = posts;
      })
    );
  }
```

to share the updated `Post[]` after delete method executed I'm trying to send stored array back to subscriber, but it doesnt help

```
  deletePost(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`).pipe(
      mapTo(res => {
        const index = this.userPosts.findIndex(p => p.id == id);
        // console.log(index);
        this.userPosts.splice(index, 1);
        return this.userPosts;
      })
    )
  }
```

what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you use `getAllUsersPosts`, `deletePost` and `userPosts` in your components?

Answer (score 1):

Create an Behaviour Subject Singleton variable in the service and make it as an observable.
Then subscribe to that observable from any component by importing the service, create an instance and subscribe to that observable singleton.

```
private publisherVariable= new BehaviorSubject<string>('empty')
castVariable = this.publisherVariable.asObservable()
this.publisherVariable.next(DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND)
```

Answer (score 0):

The persistence of userPosts will depend on the injected scope of service.

Try provding service a module scope or root scope

```
@module({
  providers:[PostService]
})
export class PostModule{}
```

Or

```
@Injectable({
  provideIn:'root'
})
export class PostService{}
```

Avoid putting postservice as provider both in module and component.

```
@Componenent({
  providers:[PostService]
})
export class PostComponent{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model and create it as a `singleton` ,use this `singleton` within your service so same reference gets passed on and updated .Just for an example

```
export class PostsModel {
    private static instance: PostsModel;
    public prop1: type = '';
    public prop2: type ='';
    static getInstance() {
        if (!PostsModel.instance) {
            PostsModel.instance = new PostsModel();
        }
        return PostsModel.instance;
    }

    static destroyInstance() {
        delete PostsModel.instance;
    }
}
```